# Using delimiter split function with IN clause in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, split, delimiter

I found a split string function on [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

It is a table-valued function that splits a delimited string. I am trying to figure out if this is the best way to call a function like this for an IN clause.

```
WHERE x.Type IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@Types, ','))
```

Would this be better as an inline function and do anything different for me?

Comment: You only posted a portion of your query and we don't really know what you are trying to do. That doesn't seem like the best usage for that function but without knowing your requirements it is hard to say.

Comment: The best way would be to use a table valued parameter in your stored procedure, but if you want to use the split function you are on the right track and it should do the trick for you what you are already doing.

Comment: the way you posted is a great way

Comment: depending on the size of the list (and the resulting table), it might be beneficial inserting the result of the function into a temp table first, just to give the optimizer a correct cardinality est

Comment: @dean not really. This is calculated once for all rows

Comment: @t-clausen.dk http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/10/28/query-performance-and-multi-statement-table-valued-functions.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys I think I will just use it this way for now. I was looking into using Table Valued Parameters and pass in through linq but it seemed like too much in all of the examples I looked at. Do you actually need to store a table to your db to use TVP? Or is it only between linq and your proc?

Comment: @dean your link doesn't mention IN and doesn't change a thing. The function is only called once because it has static parameters

Comment: @t-clausen.dk sure, but do you think it's the same whether the TVF returns 1 or 2 or 100.000 rows, as far as the optimizer is concerned?

Answer (score 0):

I have experience using 'split' function before. The only problem is performance. The query optimizer will estimate number of row too far from reality. This is because it has no idea how the data is look like in your 'where in' condition.

In my application result after split is more than 2,000 rows.
The result is more than 1 million records.
The query using 'where in (select c1 from dbo.Splie(@types))' about 15 minutes. With dynamic sql as shown below, the estimate number of row is more accurate and it take less than 5 seconds to process the query.

**Sample**

```
create table #table (
    column1 nvarchar(60),
    column2 nvarchar(60)
)
insert into #table values
('A','X'),('B','Y'),('C','Z')

declare @Types nvarchar(max) = 'A,B,C'
set @Types = concat('''', replace(@Types, ',', ''','''), '''')

declare @result table
(
  column1 nvarchar(60)
)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

select @sql = concat(
'select column2
 from #table t
 where t.column1 in (', @Types, ')'
)

insert into @result
exec sp_sqlexec @sql

select * from @result

drop table #table
```

the below statement is more optimizer friendly

```
select column2
 from #table t
 where t.column1 in ('A','B','C')
```